# Atmospheric density derivation via canonical partition function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability, atmospheric-science

As the title points out i am trying to derive the atmospheric pressure. I understand the theory behind what i should do and how, but mathematically i have no idea how to proceed.

First of all, understanding: i have a particle in the atmosphere (we assume the atmosphere has a constant temperature). Now the different states of the air particle are the different heights of it from the surface. Because the temperature is constant, that means that the kinetic energy is a constant value while the potential energy changes with the height. Now in order to find the density at a height $h$ all i need to do is to find the probability of the particle being in that height.

So this is the probability of finding the particle in a height $h$ and $h + dh$:

$$dP(z)= 1/(2\pi\hbar)^3 e^{-\beta (\vec p^2/2m + mgz)}dp_xdp_ydp_zdxdydz.$$

The first part in the above equation is the PDF of the continuous variable that is height.

Now when i try to integrate so that i can find the probability of the particle being in a height h i don't know how to proceed:

$$P(z)= \rho (z) =  \int 1/(2\pi\hbar)^3 e^{-\beta (\vec p^2/2m + mgz)}dp_xdp_ydp_zdxdydz. $$

What should the the boundaries for $x$ and $y$? For $p_x$ $p_y$ and $p_z$ i can put from minus to plus infinity, but when  i need to integrate regarding $x$ and $y$ i will get zero.
How do i solve this? In order to reach to this:

$$ \rho (z) = \rho(0)e^{-\beta M g z}.$$

Comment: What is missing here is teh normalization constant. By taking a finite volume one can evaluate all the necessary integrals and fine the distriubution. One then takes volume to infinity, but the result remains finite. I am posting this as a comment, since such calculations are done in every statistical physics textbook (and often in great detail).

Comment: isn't the first term 1/... the normalization constant ? Or rather how do i come up with that, since it is not in the PDF ?

Comment: It is a constant to assure the correct dimensionality. Normalization means that the integral of the probability over the full volume should be 1. I suggest working with a final volume - it will probably disappear from the final result.

Comment: Also - the momentum integrals can be taken right away: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: yes the boundaries for the momentum go from minus to plus infinity, but the boundaries for the x u and z components go from ? to ? (x), ? to ? (y) and from 0 to z for the z component, right?

Comment: As I say - take a finite volume, e.g., $-L/2\leq x,y\leq L/2$, $0< z<L$, normalize correctly, solve the problem and then take $L\rightarrow \infty$. I bet that $L$ disappears from the final result.

Comment: ok i will try it, thx